# Plugins to create tables

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need to create a page like that

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a9yY.jpg

Which plugins should I use to create a page very similar to this?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you actually tried **yourself**

Comment: @Pedro AF will it be something only on the administrative side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at the moment, two ways to do this.

Using the Plugin [TablePress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tablepress/) (easiest way) - [Example](https://tablepress.org/demo/)

or using the jQuery [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) plugin - [Example](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)

Regards